# External full screen button for embeded Youtube video

Tags: youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

İs there any way to trigger embedded Youtube video full screen mode? I can control video sound or play pause function with js.

```
$('#mute-toggle').on('click', function() {
var mute_toggle = $(this);

if(player.isMuted()){
    player.unMute();
    mute_toggle.text('volume_up');
}
else{
    player.mute();
    mute_toggle.text('volume_off');
}});
```

Or I can control Play and pause with Youtube Iframe Api.

```
$('#play').on('click', function () {
var status = player.getPlayerState();
player.playVideo();});
```

Is there any similar way to control Fullscreen option?